# Plotting of contours and shading them

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, contour, ncl

I am plotting contour plots using matplotlib and want to plot contour lines having an accuracy of almost eight digits (this is priority) and between a certain range may be 0.99999999 ≤ |G| ≤ 1.00000001.
I have written the following code:

```
khmax = np.arange(0,np.pi,0.01)
Ncmax = np.arange(0,np.pi,0.01)
[X, Y] = np.meshgrid(Ncmax,khmax)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

contour = plt.contour(X,Y,mod_G,30)
ax.set_title('magnitude of G')
ax.set_xlabel('Ncmax')
ax.set_ylabel('khmax')
ax.clabel(contour, inline= True, inline_spacing = -1,fmt = '%1.7f',fontsize=8)
plt.show()
```

The above code helps in plotting 30 contour lines of values like 20, 30 (just for an example). I also want to shade contours in a certain range. I tried finding using matplotlib but couldn't find any good result.
[image]
I want to get a plot somewhat in the same way as shown in the attached figure (plotting contour lines with an accuracy of 7 to eight decimal places and shading the required region).

Comment: for the shading part of the question, have you looked at `plt.contourf` ? You could mask your data before using `contourf`, to only shade a particular region

Comment: could you kindly elaborate on the use of masking the data? What I understood is that we can remove the required data and fill contour using contourf but I don't want other contour lines to vanish completely rather I want the required region to be shaded.

Comment: what I mean is, continue plotting the contour lines as you have been. You then state you want to shade contours only in a certain range. You don't say if that's a range of `X`, `Y` or `mod_G`. Let's say you want to shade in the range `a<mod_G<b`. Use that to create a mask (`mask = (mod_G > a)*(mod_G < b)`), then use that when you add your filled contours: `ax.contourf(X[mask], Y[mask], mod_G[mask], ...)`

Comment: I tried using it but it gives the error `TypeError: Input z must be 2D, not 1D`. Is reshaping required?